# How to quickly format Github reply code block?

Tags: github, formatting

Every time when i past some code snippets in Github reply box, it past with weird indentation... which i fix manually every time..  i could possibly indent/format it first in my code editor.. copy and paste directly.. which could work.. however when i am more in a rush.. and copy a block directly from my running code.. it kind of a hassle to format... or even worse when i type code directly there...

is there any browser extension? hide short-cut wizardry that im not aware of in Github to format and indent my reply quickly?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try: https://github.com/panzerdp/clipboardy, it does look like it keeps formatting not only in GitHub, but also SO and others.

[image]

Many other extensions that might be useful here: https://github.com/showcases/github-browser-extensions.